# How define request body object property as nullable in Spring Cloud Contract Groovy DSL Contract definition?

Tags: java, spring, groovy, dsl, spring-cloud-contract

I'm working on Spring Cloud based microservices, with spring cloud contract validation of client/API between services. WireMock is used in client service side tests for services API stubbing. Spring Cloud is in version *2020.0.2*. I have following Groovy contract definition:

```
Contract.make {
description "Nullable sender & receiver API contract"

request {
    method POST()
    url value(consumer(regex('/message')))
    headers {
        contentType(applicationJson())
        header("x-channelId", anyNonBlankString())
    }
    body(
            sender: [
                    toEmail            : anyEmail(),
                    firstName          : anyNonBlankString(),
                    lastName           : anyNonBlankString()
            ],
            receiver: [
                    toEmail            : anyEmail(),
                    firstName          : anyNonBlankString(),
                    lastName           : anyNonBlankString()
            ]
    )
}
response {
    status CREATED()
}
}
```

The think I want to achieve is to have both 'sender', and 'receiver' nullable. I can define nullable (DSL *optional()*) each sub-field of both, but request body can look like this:

`{sender:null, receiver:null}`

I've tried define multiple contracts for each possibility(one with both filled, second with *sender: null*, third with *receiver: null*, and both null). In this case, client service side WireMock, that uses above definitions for API stubbing, does not match wanted stubs to proper requests - e.g. when calling using request with empty *sender*, WireMock identifies as closest stub one with expected *sender* and returns 404, ignoring contract definition that expects empty *sender*.

Is there way to define field with internal structure as nullable? In documentation I've only saw possibility to make nullable field value, but not whole structure.

Answer (score 0):

If a field is potentially `null` you should create 2 contracts. 1 with it being `null` and 1 with it not being `null`.